# Serve a specific version of a requirement, otherwise default to PyPi

Tags: pip, pypi, devpi

We are successfully running a relaying `devpi` server, serving our private libraries. The server is able to serve the libraries that we upload, and relay the rest to the standard `PyPi`.

Recently, we have been forced to customize a [third-party library](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira), and we are serving our customized version with in our `devpi` server. This is working fine. But I have just realized that other versions of this library, which are not hosted in our `devpi`, but in the standard `PyPi`, are not being served.

How can I configure `devpi` to serve our libraries/versions, and relay everything else to `PyPi`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `PyPi` package name to the index package `pypi_whitelist`. Just make sure that you are using a different version number of your package then what is available on `PyPi`. Here is the description on how index whitelists work: http://doc.devpi.net/latest/userman/devpi_indices.html?highlight=whitelist#modifying-the-mirror-whitelist

Another solution would be to use a different name for you local package.